# Dynamic upload image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a script to create the image upload preview image (http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Image-Upload-Preview-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap-img-upload/).
Is working really fine, but I'm having some problems, in my form i need to create add inputs functionality, in my case, the user can add more fields dynamically, if i insert more than one input file field in my html, i have no issue, the problem starts only if i click the add button to create new input fields. Some events gets triggered and starts showing buttons that only show after i insert a image. Above i leave my add inputs fields dynamically code.

example:
https://jsbin.com/bozeyuface/edit

Js:

```
//inputs
var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Brand" name="brand[]"></div><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="title" name="title[]"></div><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="url" name="url[]"></div><div class="form-group"><div class="imageupload panel panel-default"><div class="file-tab panel-body"><label class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span>Browse</span><input type="file" name="file"></label><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button></div><div class="url-tab panel-body"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control hasclear" placeholder="Image URL"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button><input type="hidden" name="image-url[]"></div></div></div><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</a></div>');
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
})
```

Comment: Im sorry in this case wih my english, im trying to say that when i try to add dynamically new input fields, my input file preview image breacks, stops working.

Comment: You need to call `$(imageupload).imageupload()` after you append the new wrapper. This should fix it

Comment: hello @AdamAzad i tried to put $imageupload.imageupload(); but it doesnt work :S, so i tried to put before this line i add 'var $imageupload = $('.imageupload');', but if i try to insert a image in the first thumbnail, and than add one more field, the previous disapear.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code and add a unique class to the div by using the counter. If it works for you then accept the answer

```
             var x = 1; //initlal text box count
            $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
                e.preventDefault();
                if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                    x++; //text box increment

$(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4 div-'+x+'"><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Brand" name="brand[]"></div><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="title" name="title[]"></div><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="url" name="url[]"></div><div class="form-group"><div class="imageupload panel panel-default"><div class="file-tab panel-body"><label class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span>Browse</span><input type="file" name="file"></label><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button></div><div class="url-tab panel-body"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control hasclear" placeholder="Image URL"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Remove</button><input type="hidden" name="image-url[]"></div></div></div><a href="#" class="remove_field btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</a></div>').find('.div-'+x+' .imageupload').imageupload();
                }
            });

            $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
                e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
            })
        });
```